# What does the Storage Manager setting actually do?

Tags: settings, storage, photos, google-plus-photos

I'm trying to understand what the Storage Manager option in the Storage settings is supposed to do. The text says "Remove photos & videos" and I chose the option "Over 90 days old". So far, it hasn't done anything. My phone is an HTC 10.

I've found some articles introducing the feature that seem to imply that ALL backed up photos will be removed every 30/60/90 days.

In Photos, the "Free up space" option removes anything that's already backed up, regardless of age.

So does the storage manager option do what it says it does? When or how often does it run? Does it instead clear all backed up photos every X days?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog](https://mashtips.com/clean-storage-on-android-oreo/) (though I don't find *Smart storage* on my device now on 8.1 but did see that in some earlier version)

> Smart Storage is the Android Storage Manager which allows you to automatically delete the files in your device memory that has been backed up in Google Drive. The feature can be specified by a time period of deletion to take place, options range from 30, 60 or 90.
>
> This indicates the time by which the photos & videos on your device will be deleted **after being uploaded** to Google Photos

(Emphasis supplied)

I haven't used it so can't confirm that but is reasonable since "Free Storage" clears downloads and unused apps *instantly*

**Edit:** This doesn't work. Answer retained on OP's suggestions. Please see comments

Comment: That is definitely the same dialog that I'm looking at. That makes me think it'll do what I want it to do, but it hasn't done anything yet.

Comment: Like mentioned , you need to upload all today to Drive (if not set to auto upload), set that to delete after 30 days and after a month check if actually deleted or not. No immediate confirmation

Comment: Please do leave a feedback after testing- it would help others :)

Comment: Sure thing. I set it to 30 instead of 90, so I'll see what it does.

Comment: So it is now 33 days later, and nothing has happened automatically. My next experiment is to set it to 90 days and press the button next time it asks me if I want to free up space.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Interesting. Please do post your findings. All the best

Comment: I used the notification, which led me to a card in the Assistant tab of Photos, which deleted everything but the last 30 days even though I set the storage manager setting to 90 days. I am just more confused now. Maybe storage manager was working, but didn't remove anything from before the setting was turned on? Maybe the "free up space" card doesn't use that setting?

Comment: I still haven't seen it delete any photos automatically. I suspect this control only affects the "Do you want to free up space?" notification.

Comment: Thanks Jay. You are probably right. If you agree will take down my answer

Comment: You could leave it up. This discussion is good.